# Reactive form how to submit additional data

Tags: angular

I have this reactive form which submits a single value, the `title`

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="title" name="title" id="title" formControlName="title" />
            <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls['title'].dirty && formGroup.controls['title'].invalid">This is required</div>
            <button type="submit">Create</button>
        </form>
    `,
})
export class CreateDiscussionComponent {

    formGroup: FormGroup;

    constructor() {
        this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
            title: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)])
        });
    }
    onSubmit(): void {
        console.log('form value', this.formGroup.value)
    }
}
```

What If I want to add extra `default` value to the formGroup object? Like type:'discussion'.

So when I submit I expect something like this in the console

```
{title:'bla bla bla', type:'discussion'}
```

How to do this?

https://plnkr.co/edit/RY62cBHMTLLjaDCIA6mc?p=preview

Comment: what do you mean by `default` value ?

Comment: whatever the title is, the type will be equal 'discussion'. Like this {title:'this is just string', type:'disucssion'}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the constructor to this :

```
constructor() {
        this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
          title: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]),
          type : new FormControl('discussion')
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, add the type in the FormGroup definition, and set the value in the onSubmit() method. Like this:

```
formGroup: FormGroup;

constructor() {
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
        title: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]),
        type: new FormControl('')
    });
}
onSubmit(): void {
    (<FormControl>this.formGroup.controls['type']).setValue("discussion");
    console.log('form value', this.formGroup.value)
}
```

Let me know if that fits your needs!